# What is a scientific philistine called?

Tags: word-choice

A philistine is a person who knows little about culture and the arts. What is a person called who displays the same lack with regard to science?

Comment: Same question asked here (http://friendsofdarwin.com/20091230/), with the conclusion that the best phrase is either *scientific philistine* or *unenlightened*.

Comment: It would help if you expanded your question. You have given only a partial definition of *philistine*. Your question is too vague as it is. Please provide a discription of the circumstance and a sample sentence the term or phrase would fit in.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same kind of term, a present-day ***Luddite*** would eschew scientific and technological advances and milestones.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "don't know about science" you could say they are (scientifically) ignorant or illiterate.

If you mean they refuse to believe in science then they are "antiscientific".

Answer (score 0):

[*Denialist:*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/denialist)

A person who does not acknowledge the truth of a concept or proposition that is supported by the majority of scientific or historical evidence.